# How to get data from one firestore collection to another?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know How I can fetch all documents from the "playgrounds" collection that are associated with a specific document in the "solutions" collection in my React app

I have the following collections:

"users": This collection contains user documents. 
"solutions: This collection contains solution documents.
"playgrounds": This collection contains documents for different solutions in different languages. For example, a user submitted a solution in 2 different languages, such as React and Vue, so I'll create two documents in the playgrounds collection to store those solutions.

How can I fetch those two solutions in the corresponding solution document?

Please help me with that!

Comment: You mean you need high-level overview of how to achieve this ? As you haven't provided any initial start point. For Structuring firestore database go through [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo) which explains this.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for high-level overview!

Comment: what data you choose to store in the playgrounds collections document is it only solutionIds of corresponding solutions ? Because with that you can get the solutionId from playgrounds collection and get those solutions from solutions collection using where clause

Comment: I want to store an object in playgrounds collection that contains code for that playground

Comment: So Playground and solutions have 1:Many relationship, right ? Means a playground have many solutions. In that case it is better to declare solutions collection as a sub-collection of Playgrounds Documents. Refer [this](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2022/03/modeling-one-to-many-relation-in.html#:~:text=One%2Dto%2Dmany%20using%20Firestore,a%20%E2%80%9CChatRooms%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%9CCollection%E2%80%9D) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the High-level overview of your database like below as per the Provided inputs

Store Solutions in the Playgrounds collections as a sub-collection of its documents

```
Playgrounds(Collection)                       Users(Collection)
├──Document(Playground)                       ├──Document
|      └──pid                                 |  └──uid
|      └──Solutions(sub-collection)           ├──Document
|         ├──Document(Solution)               |  └──uid
|         |  └──sid
|         ├──Document(Solution)
|            └──sid
```

Now to get a solutions of a particular Playground we just have to get the corresponding subcollection

Let’s say You are in Playground A and you need to get all solutions which is posted for Playground A you will do something like :

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const fetchSolutions = async (playgroundId = "A") => {
  const playgroundRef = collection(db, "playgrounds", playgroundId, "solutions");
  const solutions = await getDocs(playgroundRef);

  solutions.forEach((solution) => {
    console.log(solution.id, " => ", solution.data());
  });
};
```

For more information go through [this docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) and [this doc](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2022/03/modeling-one-to-many-relation-in.html#:%7E:text=One%2Dto%2Dmany%20using%20Firestore,a%20%E2%80%9CChatRooms%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%9CCollection%E2%80%9D)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more question, having sub-collection can increase lots of reads. Is there any way to cache the data for sub-collection and collection and then fetch the data from the cache if it's available when a user loads the website and only fetch the newly/updated documents from firestore?

Comment: yeah there is a cache management inside firebase sdk itself you can go through [this docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data) where it explains when to get data from cache based on change type occurred on that collection or sub-collection.

Comment: One last question, does the cache persist between page reloads? Can I see the cache data in the console?

Comment: That is purely based on how you handle this data in your react code this needs to be taken care on client side

Comment: Any resources you would recommend for that?